# Почему не меняется размер шрифта в UI Text

Tags: unity3d

Делаю линейный таймбар для игры, добавил элемент UI Text (`BonusTime`), но по какой-то причине он абсолютно не реагирует на изменение Font Size. Хоть ставлю его на 5, хоть на 200 - размер один и тот же. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как это исправить?

[image]

Comment: Надеюсь, скрина будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best Fit**
Следует ли Unity игнорировать свойства размера и просто пытаться подогнать текст под прямоугольник элемента управления?

---

**Horizontal Overflow**

Метод, используемый для обработки ситуации, когда текст слишком широкий, чтобы поместиться в прямоугольнике. Возможные варианты: «Перенести» и «Переполнить».

---

**Vertical Overflow**

Метод, используемый для обработки ситуации, когда обернутый текст слишком высок, чтобы поместиться в прямоугольнике. Возможные варианты: Усечение и Переполнение.

---

Всё это ОЧЕНЬ легко узнаётся по одной из первых же ссылок [Google: Unity3d документация Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/script-Text.html) и [Translate.Google](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru&tab=TT)

Причём `Best Fit` ты сам поставил. Изначально она не стоит.

Answer (score -1):

В общем, поменял поля Horisontal Overflow и Vertical Overflow на Overflow и размер текста стал регулируемым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]